# How to merge CSV to keep special characters

Tags: c#, encoding, export-to-csv

CSV input files I have are comma delimited. When I merge them with my code then all of the special characters specific for German language are gone.

I tried to use Encoding.UTF8 parameter to StreamWriter but it did not help.

```
filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, pattern);               
fileDest = new StreamWriter(destinationFile + @"\Exps Claim.csv", true);

int i;
for (i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
{
    string file = filePaths[i];

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

    if (i > 0)
    {
        lines = lines.Skip(1).ToArray();
    }

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        fileDest.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the problem might be with the input, not the output. `File.ReadAllLines` assumes the encoding is UTF-8. If that's wrong, you can use the overload that specifies an explicit encoding (you can try `Encoding.Default` to get your "local" encoding, which may or may not be what you want).

Comment: As an aside, `File.ReadLines(...).Skip(1)` is orders of magnitude more efficient, as it does not read the whole file into memory first just to skip the first line.